# Convert and array to object in a specific format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, data-structures

Convert this array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [TEST] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => John Snow
                        [id] => 2
                    )
                [HELLO] => Array
                    (
                        [stuff] => what 
                        [more] => 0
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [TEST] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Arya Stark
                        [id] => 3
                    )
                [HELLO] => Array
                    (
                        [stuff] => dsfsdf dfsd 
                        [more] => 3
                    )
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [TEST] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Tyrion Lannister 
                        [id] => 7
                    )
                [HELLO] => Array
                    (
                        [stuff] => test 
                        [more] => 2
                    )
            )
    )
```

To:

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [TEST] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => John Snow
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                    [HELLO] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [stuff] => what 
                            [more] => 0
                        )

                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [TEST] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Arya Stark
                            [id] => 3
                        )
                    [HELLO] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [stuff] => dsfsdf dfsd 
                            [more] => 3
                        )
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [TEST] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Tyrion Lannister 
                            [id] => 7
                        )
                    [HELLO] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [stuff] => test 
                            [more] => 2
                        )
                )


        )
```

We can have more than one array within each level. This is just dummy data and the names are never TEST or HELLO, and can be anything. Let me know if you guys need more info!

Here's what I have so far:

```
function (&$data, $index) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        $output = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
             $object->$key->$index = $value[$index];
         }
    return $object;
 };
```

Comment: Please include code showing what you have tried yourself.

Comment: I tried doing it the dirty way: `foreach($data as $key=>$val)` and just create an object and assign properties within the array loop.

Comment: `foreach($data as $key=>$val)` shows us nothing. Please include the complete code that you have tried. If you can't show the fact that you are trying, why should we do it for you?

Comment: I added some code I'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function convert($data)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        foreach ($data as $k => $v)
        {
            if (is_array($v))
            {
                $obj->$k = convert($v);
            }
            else
            {
                $obj->$k = $v;
            }
        }
        return $obj;
    }
}

$data = array(
    array(
        'Test' => array(
            'Name' => 'John Snow',
            'id' => 2,
        ),
        'Hello' => array(
            'Name' => 'what',
            'id' => 3,
        ),
    ),
);
$a = convert($data);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: I modified this to work with my data and it's perfect. I was just missing the recursive part. This is twice as fast as the json solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to do like this:

```
$objects = (object)json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: I tried that...that doesn't work. It doesn't return the exact format I want.

Comment: I think this should work, and is better than mine.

Comment: @user962449 - Now it should work, just cast the outer array to an object.